# Why do we need fundamental data types in c++

Tags: c++

While revising for my test the thought came to my mind that why do we exactly need to give a variable a specific datatype? Can the our computers not differentiate between the character an integer values we store in variables? If they cant why?

Comment: Some languages don't type, but it's better in memory optimization to know the size of the variable type at compile time

Comment: They can with `auto` in C++11.

Comment: @NeilKirk does auto remove type ? I think no, it just determine automatically what is it.

Comment: Do you mean compile-time or run-time type deduction?

Comment: @MoKaT You are correct.

Comment: Static or dynamic typing boils down to personal preference given a particular problem, not more, not less.

Comment: @phresnel And performance is also a consideration.

Comment: @NeilKirk: As said, "personal preference given a particular problem". "Performance" is also a personal preference in some way, and you didn't even define _which_ performance you mean: Wattage, Disk Mileage, Uptime performance, Pixels drawn per second, Conversion rates, etc. You see, even the word "performance" is rather personal.

Comment: @phresnel Time taken for code to execute. If customers tell me program is too slow, that's not personal preference any more.

Comment: If you go to the level of machine code/assembly, yes they don't have data type. All assembly instructions takes memory/register and interprets whatever bit patterns in the given memory/register as the type of the instruction's operands. Which means you can add integers and floats together with integer addition will produce unwanted results.

Comment: @phresnel Then what's the difference between a personal preference and a business requirement? I work in number-crunchy applications, computer graphics and video coders.

Comment: @NeilKirk: I do number crunchy graphics as a hobby and crunchy log parsing as part of my job, and some other stuff, so I guess we can talk "face-to-face" (sorry, missing the proper english right now, but you know what I mean) :) Well yes, you can of course rephrase it to "Static or dynamic typing boils down to requirements given a particular problem". It's more a language thing; both terms are not standardized. I agree, I think "requirements" fits better. (But I still don't think that every performance argument beats dynamic typing; always consider "fast-enough" vs. other things)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this simple example.

```
int i;
int j;
if (b)
{
    i = 0;
}
else
{
    i = 999999;
}
```

Where should j be placed in memory? Depending on a run-time condition, either a small or large number is stored in i. But space for j is needed before this point is reached, so i must have an established size. Therefore compiler needs to know its basic type and therefore size.

Comment: +1 but not the case if everything was a reference.

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't understand your comment.

Comment: si since the compiler needs to basically reserve a memory slot for j so that a value can be later stored in it we declare j as a datatype in this case int right?

Comment: @user3219768 Sorry I don't understand that. In C++ memory for local variables must be allocated up-front, so precise size is required.